# Lubuntu does not boot into GUI

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, gui

I'm not sure what caused it, but suddenly I can't get Lubuntu to boot into the GUI. Instead I get a funky command line interface. Which is bad, because I've yet to learn more than a handfull of commands. I have no problem nukeing the thing, but it'd be nice if someone could help me. A list of commands I should try running to boot the GUI, access a change log, or anything else that might help me figure out what broke would be really appreciated.

Comment: to start the gui typ 'startx' run some these commands that might help 'sudo apt-get update' 'sudo apt-get autoremove' 'sudo dpkg configure -a'

Comment: Try `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm restart` and tell us what happened.

Comment: I get "/bin/sh: sudo: not found"

Comment: A long time ago I had something similar and the problem was that I change my $PATH. So, post the result of the command `echo $PATH` here, please.